# How to say to std::thread to stop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have two questions.

1) I want to launch some function with an infinite loop to work like a server and checking for messages in a separate thread. However I want to close it from the parent thread when I want. I'm confusing how to `std::future` or `std::condition_variable` in this case. Or is it better to create some global variable and change it to true/false from the parent thread.
2) I'd like to have something like this. Why this one example crashes during the run time?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <future>

std::mutex mu;
bool stopServer = false;

bool serverFunction()
{

    while (true)
    {
        // checking for messages...
        // processing messages

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        mu.lock();

        if (stopServer)
            break;

        mu.unlock();
    }

    std::cout << "Exiting func..." << std::endl;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread serverThread(serverFunction);

    // some stuff

    system("pause");

    mu.lock();

    stopServer = true;

    mu.unlock();

    serverThread.join();
}
```

Comment: A `std::atomic<bool> stopServer;` should suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why this one example crashes during the run time?

When you leave the inner loop of your thread, you leave the mutex locked, so the parent thread may be blocked forever if you use that mutex again.

You should use `std::unique_lock` or something similar to avoid problems like that.

Comment: I think this case does not come up since the mutex is only once aquired and released inside the main and inside the "Server"-Loop it is only left unreleased if the main action already took place.

Comment: @banana36 your solution is OK, but - as one of commenters noted - you should use std::atomic variable. The approach you used is very common.

Comment: @Skym0sh0 - we don't know the exact reason of the crash, but maybe implementation of OP's threads detects such situation (thread exit when still holding a mutex) and throws an exception? It doesn't crash on my PC, but I had to change `pause` to `sleep 5`.

Comment: @banana36 - oh, and you don't need mutex if the condition is that simple, `std::atomic` alone will be ok.

Comment: @FreddieChopin Yeah, you are right. And your initial answer is perfect, too. Then you'll be on the safe side and everything is ok.

Answer (score 1):

You leave your mutex locked.  Don't lock mutexes manually in 999/1000 cases.

In this case, you can use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` to create a RAII lock-holder that will avoid this problem.  Simply create it in a scope, and have the lock area end at the end of the scope.

```
{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
  stopServer = true;
}
```

in `main` and

```
  {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mu);
    if (stopServer)
        break;
  }
```

in `serverFunction`.

Now in this case your mutex is pointless.  Remove it.  Replace `bool stopServer` with `std::atomic<bool> stopServer`, and remove all references to `mutex` and `mu` from your code.

An atomic variable can safely be read/written to from different threads.

However, your code is still busy-waiting.  The right way to handle a server processing messages is a condition variable guarding the message queue.  You then stop it by front-queuing a stop server message (or a flag) in the message queue.

This results in a server thread that doesn't wake up and pointlessly spin nearly as often.  Instead, it blocks on the condition variable (with some spurious wakeups, but rare) and only really wakes up when there are new messages or it is told to shut down.

```
template<class T>
struct cross_thread_queue {
  void push( T t ) {
    {
      auto l = lock();
      data.push_back(std::move(t));
    }
    cv.notify_one();
  }
  boost::optional<T> pop() {
    auto l = lock();
    cv.wait( l, [&]{ return halt || !data.empty(); } );
    if (halt) return {};
    T r = data.front();
    data.pop_front();
    return std::move(r); // returning to optional<T>, so we'll explicitly `move` here.
  }
  void terminate() {
    {
      auto l = lock();
      data.clear();
      halt = true;
    }
    cv.notify_all();
  }
private:
  std::mutex m;
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock() {
    return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(m);
  }
  bool halt = false;
  std::deque<T> data;
  std::condition_variable cv;
};
```

We use `boost::optional` for the return type of `pop` -- if the queue is halted, pop returns an empty optional.  Otherwise, it blocks until there is data.

You can replace this with anything optional-like, even a `std::pair<bool, T>` where the first element says if there is anything to return, or a `std::unique_ptr<T>`, or a `std::experimental::optional`, or a myriad of other choices.

```
cross_thread_queue<int> queue;

bool serverFunction()
{
  while (auto message = queue.pop()) {
    // processing *message
    std::cout << "Processing " << *message << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "Exiting func..." << std::endl;

  return true;
}

int main()
{
  std::thread serverThread(serverFunction);

  // some stuff
  queue.push(42);

  system("pause");

  queue.terminate();

  serverThread.join();
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9553a32820d868a8).